# How to get the number of current connections to an external web service

Tags: linux, netstat

My application makes many requests in a day to a webservice (say 172.20.20.20:11111) on a different server.

I would like to know how I can count the number of connections that are established (the number of current connections to the external webservice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run

```
netstat -n | grep 172.20.20.20:11111 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

netstat shows the established TCP sessions. First grep filters the server / port combinations, the second filters established sessions, and finally wc is used to count the number of connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can log all new outgoing connections to "172.20.20.20:11111" with iptables

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "ConnectionTracking"`

After that you can get/count all new connections to given IP from your logfile with something like `grep "ConnectionTracking" /var/log/YOUR_LOGFILE | wc -l`